# how to sort a multi dimensional model

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm using PySide to write a plugin browser. The available plugins are stored in a three dimensional model like this:

```
pluginType/pluginCategory/pluginName
```

e.g.:

```
python/categoryA/toolA
python/categoryB/toolAA
```

etc.

In my custom view, I am showing all tools of a given plugin type (i.e. "python") in a list, regardless of their category:

```
(python)
categoryA/toolA
categoryA/toolB
categoryA/toolC
categoryB/toolAA
categoryB/toolBB
categoryB/toolCC
```

I am now wondering how to best sort this view, so the tools are sorted by name regardless of their parent category. The sorting method in my current proxy model yields a sorted list per category like the above one, but what I am after is this:

```
(python)
categoryA/toolA
categoryB/toolAA
categoryA/toolB
categoryB/toolBB
categoryA/toolC
categoryB/toolCC
```

Do I have to make my proxy model convert the multi-dimensional source model into a one-dimensional one in order to achieve this or is there a better way? I would love to be able to sync the custom view with a standard tree view which is why I chose the multi-dimensional model.

Thanks,
frank

edit 1:
Here is what I have as a simplified example. I'm not sure if this is the way to go about it (changing the model structure into a 1-dimensional model), and if it is, I'm not sure how to create the data in the proxy model properly so it is linked with the source model as expected.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class ToolModel(QStandardItemModel):
    '''multi dimensional model'''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTools()

    def setTools(self):
        for contRow, container in enumerate(['plugins', 'python', 'misc']):
            contItem = QStandardItem(container)
            self.setItem(contRow, 0, contItem)
            for catRow, category in enumerate(['catA', 'catB', 'catC']):
                catItem = QStandardItem(category)
                contItem.setChild(catRow, catItem)
                for toolRow, tool in enumerate(['toolA', 'toolB', 'toolC']):
                    toolItem = QStandardItem(tool)
                    catItem.setChild(toolRow, toolItem)

class ToolProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    '''
    proxy model for sorting and filtering.
    need to be able to sort by toolName regardless of category,
    So I might have to convert the data from sourceModel to a 1-dimensional model?!
    Not sure how to do this properly.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        index = 0
        for contRow in xrange(model.rowCount()):
            containerItem = model.item(contRow, 0)
            for catRow in xrange(containerItem.rowCount()):
                categoryItem = containerItem.child(catRow)
                for itemRow in xrange(categoryItem.rowCount()):
                    toolItem = categoryItem.child(itemRow)
                    # how to create new, 1-dimensional data for self?



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = QWidget()
mainWindow.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())

model = ToolModel()
proxyModel = ToolProxyModel()
proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
treeView = QTreeView()
treeView.setModel(model)
treeView.expandAll()
listView = QListView()

listView.setModel(proxyModel)

mainWindow.layout().addWidget(treeView)
mainWindow.layout().addWidget(listView)
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

edit:
Or maybe I should be asking how to best prepare a source model so that it can be used by QTreeView but also sorted in the above mentioned way for display in a list view?!

Comment: I don't think I understand. You don't have 3 `CatA` or `CatB`, you have 1 with each having 3 children. How would that work with your sorting? You want to separate these children and duplicate `CatA`, `CatB`, etc...?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to understand; is it possible to write a proxy model that can give me the above described sorting behavior with a hierarchical model as the source. Maybe I should start with a "flat" source model (i.e. one item per row and no hierarchy) and use a proxy model for creating a TreeView instead? I could derive the hierarchy after the fact from attributes attached to the tools.

Comment: I am still trying to grasp your intent. What is the purpose of those `Cat*` if not grouping the items inside them? With your sorting, it would feel weird for me. Perhaps you should switch the hierarchy order: `Tool-Category`. That way it would feel much more natural. Other than that, you can certainly define a custom sort (i.e. sort according to children) by subclassing `QSortFilterProxy` and reimplementing `lessThan` according to your needs, but for the way you want it to work you need to separate those children so that you have 1 child per category.

Comment: it's just a special view that shows all tools in all categories in a grid/list, then allow the user to filter to only tools of a certain categories.

Comment: It's a special view that lists all tools in a container (top level, e.g. "python") regardless of their category (the category is just an attribute to the tool in this case). Alternatively I'd like to have the option to show a tree view where things are displayed container/category/tools. I am already subclassing QSortFilterProxy and implementing lessThan, but that won't traverse the tools' parent (category). In other words I am trying to display two different hierachies based on the same model. One as Type/Category/Tool, the other as Type/Tool

Comment: So you want to take out `Category` all together for one view? That is doable with a custom `QAbstractProxyModel`.

Comment: yes, I guess that's what I'm after and don't know how to best do it. Is my above example code even close?

Answer (score 0):

Use a QTableView and sort (using the sort proxy) by the tool_name column.